# windows command prompt curl POST to run Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, curl, azure-devops, cmd, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to run an Azure DevOps pipeline from the windows command prompt using curl.
Based on Microsoft documentation ( [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) ) I should be able to run a pipeline by posting:

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/%7BpipelineId%7D/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

I am able to GET using the command:

```
curl -u :<PAT> https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

However, I can't figure out how to do a POST for DevOps using curl to run the pipeline.

I have tried the following:

```
curl -s -X POST -L https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1 -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic <PAT>"
```

But this returns the error

```
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem which consisted of numerous steps:

1. Log the API call from the DevOps website to get the correct format of the json-body ( [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440416/pipelines-runs-run-pipeline-howto-provide-pipeline-resource-in-request-bod?rq=1) ).
2. Format the json-body with extra double quotation signs.
3. Use the {project}-id instead of the ascii-name since it included a special character which the command prompt misinterpret.

Hence the complete curl command was:

```
curl -X POST -u :<PAT> "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{""stagesToSkip"": ""[]"", ""resources"": {""repositories"": {""self"": {""refName"": ""refs/heads/master""}}}}"
```