# How do I run an Azure DevOps pipeline using the Azure DevOps NuGet and at the same time specify resources?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm building upon the question asked in "[How do I queue a build and only run specific stages with the azure devops nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74044109/how-do-i-queue-a-build-and-only-run-specific-stages-with-the-azure-devops-nuget)", but I have a need for extending it further, to specify some resources.

In my pipeline YAML, I have defined a "pipeline" resource, that is ultimately used to download a build artifact.

I can use the same `PipelinesHttpClient` mentioned in the referenced question to retrieve a pipeline run that was performed manually (note: important to use the client from the "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi" namespace, rather than the one in the older "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Pipelines.WebApi" namespace).

Through that instance I see that it has a `Resources` property that further has a `Repositories` property, with an item named "self", containing an instance of "Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi.RepositoryResource".

The problem comes when trying to replicate this instance in code.
I ultimately get stuck on trying to instantiate a `RunResourcesParameters` instance I need for assigning to a `RunPipelineParameters` instance's `Resources` property.

If I just instantiate a "vanilla" `RunPipelineParameters` instance, I end up with its `Resources` property being null:
[image: Vanilla RunPipelineParameters instance]

I see that its type is `RunResourcesParameters`, so tried instantiating that. However, it won't let me do that, due to its protection level:

`var runResourcesParameters = new RunResourcesParameters();`
[image: RunResourcesParameters ctor access error]

It has an other ctor as well, but the same goes for that:

`var runResourcesParameters2 = new RunResourcesParameters((ISecuredObject)(new object()));`
[image: RunResourcesParameters ctor access error v2]

It's defined like this:
[image: RunResourcesParameters type]
and further like this:

[image: BaseSecuredObject]

The same problem of course occurs if I try object initialization on the `RunPipelineParameters` instance:

`var runParameters = new RunPipelineParameters{Resources = };`
[image: RunPipelineParameters object init]

`var runParameters = new RunPipelineParameters{Resources = new RunResourcesParameters()};`
[image: RunPipelineParameters object init v2]

**What am I doing wrong?**

I've looked at the "[.NET client samples](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples)", but it doesn't contain anything for `PipelinesHttpClient`.
I note that the repo has been set in read-only mode back in 2021.

The NuGet page for the "Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" NuGet package shows that there is a brand new 19.x series package in preview these days, so possibly the samples will be revived in combination with that?

Comment: I can reproduce the same issue when using the Resources.Pipelines or Resource.Repositories. This issue exists both in Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client 16.x and 19.x. It seems that the sdk itself has some issues. Can you share your nuget package version with us?

Comment: I'm using the latest available 16.x version: 16.205.1

Comment: I have found the solution to solve this issue. You can refer to the answer and check if it can work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, we can use the following code:

```
    string json = @"{ 'Builds': {}, 'Containers': {}, 'Repositories': {}, 'Pipelines': {}, 'Packages': {} }";
    RunResourcesParameters test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RunResourcesParameters>(json);

    test.Pipelines.Add(name, PipelineResource);

    parameters.Resources = test;
```

Full code sample:

```
using System;

using System.IO;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using Microsoft.Azure.Pipelines.WebApi;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApp5

{

    class Program

    {


        static async Task Main(string[] args)

        {


            var vssConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/orgname"), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "PAT"));

            var name = "pipelineresourcename";

            var pipelineClient = new PipelinesHttpClient(vssConnection.Uri, vssConnection.Credentials);

            var PipelineResource = new PipelineResourceParameters();

      
            PipelineResource.Version = "Pipelineresourceversion";

            var parameters = new RunPipelineParameters();



 

            string json = @"{ 'Builds': {}, 'Containers': {}, 'Repositories': {}, 'Pipelines': {}, 'Packages': {} }";
            RunResourcesParameters test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RunResourcesParameters>(json);

            test.Pipelines.Add(name, PipelineResource);

            parameters.Resources = test;



           

            var run = await pipelineClient.RunPipelineAsync(parameters, "projectid", pipelineid);

        }

    }

}
```

When you run the c# sample, the pipeline resource info will be passed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use this soon, to see if it meets my requirements.

Comment: Feel free to share the result with us.

Comment: Thank you very much, @kevin-lu-msft Through your JSON deserialization trick I was able to solve my problem. I will post an "answer" to my own question as well, with some more slightly related information that might come in handy for others later.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to my comment thanking @kevin-lu-msft for the help towards solving my problem, I will also post some additional information.

Through that JSON deserialization trick of his, I was able to run my pipeline.
However, it kept failing, as I have a requirement to reference a specific build, to download some build artifacts.
I only produce these build artifacts for a release build, where I've also built for a tag. rather than a branch.

By specifying only the name of the pipeline I wanted to refer to, it kept giving me a reference to the default branch, which didn't contain the expected build artifacts, and therefore failed (as it should).

Then I stumbled upon someone else [describing their use of the "PipelineResourceParameters" type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440416/pipelines-runs-run-pipeline-howto-provide-pipeline-resource-in-request-bod#comment115836380_65445210).
There it's mentioned that the name used in the pipeline resource should match the one used in the actual resource declaration (in the build pipeline) (my interpretation).

I then proceeded to view the metadata for an existing manual run:

```cs
var existingRun = await pipelinesClient.GetRunAsync(AdoProjectName, buildDefinitionId, buildId);
```

Its "Url" property leads to a JSON document, that included a "pipelines" section:

```yml
        "pipelines": {
            "$(PipelineResourceIdentifier)": {
                "pipeline": {
                    "url": "some_url",
                    "id": some_id,
                    "revision": some_revision,
                    "name": "some_name",
                    "folder": "\\some_folder"
                },
                "version": "some_tag"
            }
        }
```

In my pipeline, I actually use that "$(PipelineResourceIdentifier)":

```yml
variables:
  - name: PipelineResourceIdentifier
    value: "Build"

resources:
  # Reference a build pipeline, to ease download of build artifacts
  # For details, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: $(PipelineResourceIdentifier) # Doc: "Identifier for the resource used in pipeline resource variables"
      source: "some_pipeline" # Doc: "Name of the pipeline that produces an artifact"
      trigger: none # Doc: "A new run of the current pipeline is NOT triggered whenever the resource pipeline successfully completes a run"

[...]
      # For details, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#download-for-pipelines
      - download: $(PipelineResourceIdentifier)
        artifact: $(GitVersionArtifactIdentifier) # Doc: "Artifact to download, optional; defaults to all the artifacts from the resource"
        displayName: "GitVersion - Step 1/2 (download build artifact from main build)"
```

As you can see, the reason for specifying the pipeline resource identifier as a pipeline variable is due to reusing it later on for build artifact download purposes.

Turns out then that the "PipelineResourceParameters" type takes this very literally. As mentioned above, it does NOT work if you simply specify the actual name of the pipeline. It also does NOT work if you specify the VALUE of that pipeline variable, i.e. "Build" in this case.

It has to literally be like this, in fact:

```cs
runResourcesParameters.Pipelines.Add("$(PipelineResourceIdentifier)", pipelineResourceParameters);
```

This seems a bit fragile, if you happen to change the name of the pipeline variable at some point...
Anyway, it works like a charm!